# SMD LED maximum brightness

Tags: led

I have 2 questions:

1. I connected a 27 ohm series resistor to an SMD LED, about 47mA flows. Why doesn't damage the LED even though 46mA is higher than the absolute maximum rating of 30mA in the datasheet?

[image]

2. How can I get maximum brightness from the LED? Is the only way to put 20mA through it?

[LED](http://www.qt-brightek.com/datasheet/QBLP601_series.pdf)

Comment: It's not guaranteed to fail if you exceed Absolute Maximum Ratings, it's just not guaranteed to work..

Comment: Why do you think it does not damage the LED?

Comment: I see blinking it just visually? It resume blinking about 2-3 days.

Comment: High likely the lifetime will be decreased faster.

Comment: OK. How about my 2nd question?

Comment: The current is set by R4.  Is there any reason you chose 27 ohms?

Comment: No. I've got board. It has a design just like the schematic, I don't understand how it is not damaged.The designer said it was for brightness boost. Should i go this way??

Comment: The data sheet does NOT match the part number in the schematic. Please fix. We need the precise part number and the exact data sheet. Everything in your circuit needs to be correct and unambiguous. And also the 3.3 volt supply source needs to be specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. While the LED has an Absolute Max rating of 30mA, it does not mean it will be immediately damaged when more than 30mA flows. It is just the safe DC rating after which the operation of the LED is not guaranteed in any way.
2. No the LED is not brightest at 20mA. 20mA is the rated current at which the LED parameters are measured and specified. You can use the LED at higher current and it would be brighter, but also it would not match the rated values.

Please note that the LED is also rated to operate at pulsed currents up to 125mA, so that would give the highest apparent brightness at average current of 15.6mA.

As it is now, the LED is used beyond its ratings and has shorter lifetime due to the constant overcurrent damaging it. Simply get a different LED that is brighter to begin with. And give feedback to the designer about the circuit damaging the LEDs.

Comment: Pulse currents seem to work for me to increase led brightness.